# Replacing \r\n (newline characters) after running json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace, json

So when I run json_encode, it grabs the \r\n from MySQL aswell. I have tried rewriting strings in the database to no avail. I have tried changing the encoding in MySQL from the default latin1_swedish_ci to ascii_bin and utf8_bin. I have done tons of str_replace and chr(10), chr(13) stuff. I don't know what else to say or do so I'm gonna just leave this here....

```
$json = json_encode($new);
if(isset($_GET['pretty'])) {
echo str_replace("\/", "/", jsonReadable(parse($json)));
} else {
$json = str_replace("\/", "/", $json);
echo parse($json);
}
```

The jsonReadable function is from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#92539) and the parse function is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395379/problem-when-retrieving-text-in-json-format-containing-line-breaks-with-jquery). The str_replaces that are already in there are because I am getting weird formatted html tags like </h1>. Finally, $new is an array which is crafted above. Full code upon request.

*Help me StackOverflow. You're my only hope*

Comment: Have you read the JSON specification yet? http://www.json.org/

Comment: Yeah I have worked with JSON for a long time, thing is that the output of this script is being picked up by flash for a CMS & flash no-likey the \r\n stuff. It just inserts new lines which we don't want. We want <br />. And yes, I tried nl2br, no luck.

Comment: So then someone decided to not implement JSON properly in the Flash. Lovely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does the string contain "\r\n" (as in 0x0D 0x0A) or the literal string '\r\n'? If it's the former, this should remove any newlines.

```
$json = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $json);
```

Optionally, replace the second parameter "" with "<br />" if you'd like to replace the newlines with a br tag. For the latter case, try the following:

```
$json = preg_replace('!\\r?\\n!', "", $json);
```

Comment: This didn't work, they are still there. I think *maybe* it has something to do with MySQL :/

Answer (score 7):

Don't replace it in the JSON, replace it in the source before you encode it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, i used:

```
$p_num = trim($this->recp);
$p_num = str_replace("\n", "", $p_num);
$p_num = str_replace("\r", ",", $p_num);
$p_num = str_replace("\n",',', $p_num);
$p_num = rtrim($p_num, "\x00..\x1F");
```

Not sure if this will help with your requirements.

Comment: This also didn't work, again, I think this might be a MySQL issue. Thank you for the attempt though! *high-five*