# Converting Newlines in JSON array to line breaks: JSON_decode and nl2br

Tags: php, json, nl2br

I cannot get the below array to replace the carriage return and newline with an HTML break `<br />`

JSON Array:

> {"Fruit":"Apple","Veggies":"Carrot\r\nCelery\r\n\r\nCucumbers"}

I'm trying this and having no luck:

> $html = json_decode(nl2br($json),true);

The line breaks are visible in the source code of the HTML itself however I cannot get the `<br />` code to replace the 'newlines'.

I've tried this suggestion as well and it did not work either:
 [Replacing \r\n (newline characters) after running json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230170/replacing-r-n-newline-characters-after-running-json-encode)

Comment: how did you get the json? I think is better replace before make the json encode or after if you dont have the possibility of edit the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `nl2br()` after JSON is decoded, not on the JSON array source.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try

```
$arJson = array( 'fruit' => 'apple', 
                 'veggies' => array( 'carrot', 'celery', 'cucumbers' ) );

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

print json_encode( $arJson );
```

Which returns a JSON

Then use jQuery or your favorite library( even a custom build one ) to send an ajax request to the page.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'frtsnvgs.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function( oData ) {
        $.each( oData, function( key, value ) {
            document.write( key + ': ' + value + '<br>' );
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This may help you

```
$json = '{"Fruit":"Apple","Veggies":"Carrot\r\nCelery\r\n\r\nCucumbers"}';
$json = json_decode($json,true);
array_walk($json, function(&$val){$val = html_entity_decode(nl2br($val));});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$html = json_decode(nl2br($json,false),true);
```

Syntax: `nl2br(string,xhtml)`

With: `xhtml` Optional. A boolean value that indicates whether or not to use XHTML compatible line breaks:

`TRUE`- Default. Inserts `<br />`

`FALSE` - Inserts `<br>`

with `<br />` it make json error.