# json_decode(json_encode(an indexed array)) gives NULL

Tags: php, mysql, json

i encode the user entred testarea content with  json_encode
here is how it storred in mysql (there is a return to line after "aaa")

```
{"content":"aaa
bbb"}
```

now when i get the the content from database and trying to decoded it using json_decode, i get NULL for this, instead of what expected.

what wrrong? a bug in PHP?

EDIT 1: more details

```
$data =array('content'=>$textareaText);
$addres_insert = "INSERT INTO `rtable` (`data`) VALUES ('".json_encode($data)."');";
$rows = mysql_query($addres_insert);
```

then to get the content

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `rtable` WHERE id =  '".$id."'";
        $rows = mysql_query($query);
    if ( $rows ){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rows);
        $res['data'] = json_decode($row['data']);//i tryed substr($row['data'],3) but didn't work
    }
```

Comment: Can we see how you encode / decode this array ?

Comment: It could be utf8. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-php for almost same discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript and JSON do not allow line returns to be contained within a string. You need to escape them.

`json_encode()` should escape them automatically for you.

Here is the output of my playing with your JSON code supplied on the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > $json = '{"content":"aaa
php ' bbb"}';
php > var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
NULL
```

As you can see when I escape your line return it works just fine:

```
php > $json = '{"content":"aaa\n bbb"}';
php > var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
array(1) {
  ["content"]=>
  string(8) "aaa
 bbb"
}
```

This is also further discussed in a previous question relating to a similar problem: [Problem when retrieving text in JSON format containing line breaks with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395379/problem-when-retrieving-text-in-json-format-containing-line-breaks-with-jquery)

Comment: excelent , so for sur the content i get from mysql should be escaped too with some php fucntion . thanks