# json_decode return "NULL" help me

Tags: php, json

I get json string:

```
$response = '{"retcode":"0","retmsg":"OK","cre_id_enc":"","cre_type":"","fee_type":"1","listid":"1221085301201410240000001024","out_trade_no":"201410246763831","partner":"1221085301","pay_fee":"0","sign":"PTamau\x2BjkynA00cASKJ6Nd3QwFSBP44TKSqmmdCd\x2F\x2B0o8ViSt3fp5vQr0Fc73U42NhtImfnHzbynoUjURiNLW5O4hI61xkG\x2F97JRPRE0nHuvtAumqXfbVCsLveugE52HRZsJvm3EG7pL6GlhYf8ng6qxiUrDyn89PFVZ04Wd8Gk\x3D","total_fee":"1000000","unfreeze_fee":"1000000","user_name_enc":""}';
```

I use json_decode to convert this string to array,but it return "NULL".
I found `"sign":"PTamau\x2BjkynA00cASKJ6Nd3QwFSBP44TKSqmmdCd\x2F\x2B0o8ViSt3fp5vQr0Fc73U42NhtImfnHzbynoUjURiNLW5O4hI61xkG\x2F97JRPRE0nHuvtAumqXfbVCsLveugE52HRZsJvm3EG7pL6GlhYf8ng6qxiUrDyn89PFVZ04Wd8Gk\x3D","total_fee":"1000000"` can't use json_decode.
it contains ASCII code like '\x2F' , '\x2B', '\x3D'.
so I try to convert to utf8, like this `$response = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $response);`. 
it's no useful.the response string still contains `'\x2F' , '\x2B', '\x3D'` and `json_decode` still return NULL.

someone can help me and forgive me my poor English!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an answer on a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400560/json-decode-problems-in-php), you need to escape the backslashes:

```
$json = str_replace( '\x', '\\\\x', $response );
```

and then pass $json to json_decode

Comment: thank you! I found `$json = str_replace( '\x', '\\\\x', $response );` is right

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the single quotes.

```
print_r('\x2F');
\x2F
print_r("\x2F");
/
```

Single quotes will not interpret the backslash sequence, which leaves you with malformed JSON which only allows `\\` and `\"`, AFAIK. If you already have the single-backslash string, do what Vasilis says.