# Not getting response when data has \r\n

Tags: json

I am new to JSON. I am trying to retrieve JSON data from a file using the below code.

```
$.getJSON("test1.json",function(data){
```

The data in file is as mentioned below:

```
{
    "Ad": [
        {
            "ImpUrl": "http:\/\/test.com\/18148682\/385490696\/?_RM_HTML_CALLBACK_=callbackFunction",
            "ClkUrl": "http:\/\/test.com\/HomeLending_TDB_HP_B_EN_b000-00-647.html\/446f783068314a6e3232674144484e69?_RM_HTML_CALLBACK_=callbackFunction",
            "FileUrl": "http:\/\/test.com\/385490696\/?_RM_HTML_CALLBACK_=callbackFunction",
            "Text": " \r\n\r\n \"Great\r\n <\/div> \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n Great rates, legendary service.\r\n <\/h5>\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n <\/a>\r\n A mortgage with all the comforts of home.\r\n <\/li>\r\n \r\n <\/ul>\r\n \r\n Calculate your rates and payment<\/span><\/a>\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n > Buying a Home? <\/a>
            \r\n \r\n> Refinancing?<\/a>\r\n <\/p>\r\n <\/div>\r\n<\/div>",
        }
    ]
}
```

When I **remove** all the **"\" and "\n\r"** from the data it starts going inside the function, but with these it does not.

Thanks,
-Ritesh

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395379/problem-when-retrieving-text-in-json-format-containing-line-breaks-with-jquery

Comment: My question is if I receive this kind of data from a server, what to do so that it goes inside the function mentioned above.

Comment: I saw the post before I posted my question. In the other post the guy is uploading the JSON data so he can encode escape sequences. In my case I am a consumer and this data is coming from a server.

Comment: Is there really a hard newline within the `Text` property value?  This is not allowed in JSON, all newlines need to be represented as `\n` (or `\r\n`).

Comment: @IanRoberts Unfortunalety,This is the response I am getting in JSON response.

Comment: Then it's not JSON.  It might look a bit like JSON but it's not valid, and it's the _server_ that needs to be fixed to send valid responses.

Answer (score 0):

Ritesh Your JSON data is not well formated, Check " closing and ending. I see there is an extra quote near "Great.